# How to use multiple button for multiple submit event in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, html-table

I am trying to save data of different rows of table in database using different submit button for each row.

```
echo '<form style="text-align:center" id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">';
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td nowrap='nowrap'><label>".$rowsum['student_name1']."</label><input type='hidden' name='studentId1' id='studentId1' value=".$rowsum['student_name1']." /></td>";
        echo "<td align='center'>
                <select id='Status1' name='Status1'><option value='NP'>Not Present</option><option value='P'>Present</option></select></td>";
        echo "<td align='center'>
                <input style='font-weight:bold; background:#FFFFFF; text-align:right; color:#000000;' disabled='disabled' name='mar1' type='text' id='mar1' size='5' maxlength='5' value='".$mar1."' /></td>";
        echo "<td align='center'>
                <input style='font-weight:bold; background:#FFFFFF; text-align:right; color:#000000;' disabled='disabled' name='hin1' type='text' id='hin1' size='2' maxlength='2' value='".$hin1."' /></td>";
        echo "<td align='center'>
                <input style='font-weight:bold; background:#FFFFFF; text-align:right; color:#000000; border:hidden;' type='text' id='eng1' disabled='disabled' name='eng' value='".$eng1."' size='2' maxlength='2' /></td>";
        echo "<td align='center'>
                <input style='font-weight:bold; color:#000000; background:#FFFFFF; text-align:right; border:hidden;' name='hist1' id='hist1' value='".$hist1."' disabled='disabled' size='2' maxlength='2' /></td>";
        echo "<td align='center'>
                <input style='font-weight:bold; background:#FFFFFF; text-align:right; color:#000000; border:hidden;' name='geo1' id='geo1' value='".$geo1."' disabled='disabled' size='5' maxlength='5' type='text' /></td>";
        echo "<td align='center'>
                <input style='font-weight:bold; background:#FFFFFF; text-align:right; color:#000000; border:hidden;' type='text' name='marks1' disabled='disabled' id='marks1' value='".$marks1."' size='5' maxlength='5' /></td>";
        echo "<td align='center'>
                <input type='submit' name='SaveBat1' id='SaveBat1' value='Save' />
            </td></tr>";
        echo '</form>';

    //}
    $sql_result1 = mysql_query("SELECT `student_name` FROM `bat_score_board` WHERE `student_name` =  '$student1'") or die(mysql_error());
    $sql_row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_result1);
    if(!empty($sql_row1['student_name'])) {
        //echo "Id exists - " .  $sql_row1['student_name'] . "\n";
        $sqlup1 = "update bat_score_board set student_name='$student1', status='$status1', mar='$mar1', hin='$hin1', eng='$eng1', hist='$hist1', geo='$geo1', marks='$marks1' where student_name='$student1'";
        $resultup1 = mysql_query($sqlup1);
        //print_r($resultup1); exit();
    } else {
        //echo "Id no longer exists - " . $sql_row1['student_name'] . "\n";
        $sqlBat1 = "INSERT INTO bat_score_board(student_name, status, mar, hin, eng, hist, geo, marks)VALUES('$student1', '$status1', '$mar1', '$hin1', '$eng1', '$hist1', '$geo1', '$marks1')";
        $resultBat1 = mysql_query($sqlBat1);
        //print_r($resultBat1); exit();
    }
```

This is what I tried for each row using PHP (with different name, id etc for each row) but when I press the submit button of first row to save data of first row in database it saved successfully but when I press submit button of second row at that time data of first row which I submitted before get '0' (zero) in database and same time data of second row's get saved in database in different row.

After this submission again I tried to save data of first at that time data of first row get saved but data of second row get '0'. Can anybody tell me where I am going wrong?

Comment: Are you using only one form?

Comment: where do you define and set `$student1` and other variables?

Comment: @Ander2 i am using separate form for every row.

Comment: @Amir i am defining all variable at the time of retrieving them from Database

Comment: @Shri Can you post the missing loop parts of your code? Is there any loop in the query part ?

Comment: @Ander2 i am using this

require("/includes/commonClass.php");
 
 $classObj = new commonclass;
 
 $postedData = $classObj->getRequestedData();
 
 $setsession = $classObj->validsessionmanager();



$classObj->getTempteam();
              
$resultum = $classObj->selectSql($condum);
$rowum = $classObj->fetchData($resultum);
   
foreach($rowum as $rowsum)
    {
 $student1 = $rowsum['student_name1'];
 $student2 = $rowsum['student_name2'];
 $student3 = $rowsum['student_name3'];
 $student4 = $rowsum['student_name4'];
 
 
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it this way

```
<?php
 if(isset($_POST['SUBMIT BUTTON 1 NAME'])) {
  // YOUR 1ST INSERT QUERY
 }
 if(isset($_POST['SUBMIT BUTTON 2 NAME'])) {
  // YOUR 2ND INSERT QUERY
 }
 if(isset($_POST['SUBMIT BUTTON 3 NAME'])) {
  // YOUR 3RD INSERT QUERY
 }
?>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: thanks @Roger i just tried this but now the problem is data is saving in database well but not retrieving back to page.

Comment: @Shri: Happy that I could help

Answer (score 1):

```
check this out dude, 
   <?php
    class Connection {
        var $hostname, $username, $password, $database;
        function __construct() {

            //  local
            $this->hostname = "localhost"; 
            $this->username = "root"; 
            $this->password = ""; 
            $this->database = "test"; 
            $this->dbConnection(); 
        }

        public function dbConnection () {
            $connection = mysql_connect($this->hostname,$this->username,$this->password) or die ('Cannot make a connection');
            if ($connection) {
                $selectDB = mysql_select_db($this->database) or die ('Cannot select database');
            }
        }
    }
    $connect = new Connection();

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM bat_score_board";
    $row = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query($sql));

    $cricketer_name = $row[1];
    $status = $row[2];
    $mar = $row[3];
    $hin = $row[4];
    $eng = $row[5];
    $hist = $row[6];
    $geo = $row[7];
    $marks = $row[8];



    echo '<form style="text-align:center;" id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">';
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td nowrap='nowrap'><label>".$cricketer_name."</label><input type='hidden' name='studentId1' id='studentId1' value=".$cricketer_name." /></td>";
            echo "<td align='center'>
                    <select id='Status1' name='Status1'><option value='NP'>Not Present</option><option value='P'>Present</option></select></td>";
            echo "<td align='center'>
                    <input style='font-weight:bold; background:#FFFFFF; text-align:right; color:#000000;' readonly name='mar1' type='text' id='mar1' size='5' maxlength='5' value='".$mar."' /></td>";
            echo "<td align='center'>
                    <input style='font-weight:bold; background:#FFFFFF; text-align:right; color:#000000;' readonly name='hin1' type='text' id='hin1' size='2' maxlength='2' value='".$hin."' /></td>";
            echo "<td align='center'>
                    <input style='font-weight:bold; background:#FFFFFF; text-align:right; color:#000000; border:hidden;' type='text' id='eng1' readonly name='eng1' value='".$eng."' size='2' maxlength='2' /></td>";
            echo "<td align='center'>
                    <input style='font-weight:bold; color:#000000; background:#FFFFFF; text-align:right; border:hidden;' name='hist1' id='hist1' value='".$hist."' readonly size='2' maxlength='2' /></td>";
            echo "<td align='center'>
                    <input style='font-weight:bold; background:#FFFFFF; text-align:right; color:#000000; border:hidden;' name='geo1' id='geo1' value='".$geo."' readonly size='5' maxlength='5' type='text' /></td>";
            echo "<td align='center'>
                    <input style='font-weight:bold; background:#FFFFFF; text-align:right; color:#000000; border:hidden;' type='text' name='marks1' readonly  id='marks1' value='".$marks."' size='5' maxlength='5' /></td>";
            echo "<td align='center'>
                    <input type='submit' name='SaveBat1' id='SaveBat1' value='Save' />
                </td></tr>";
            echo '</form>';

        //}

        if ( isset($_POST["Status1"]) ) {

        echo "hello";
        $cricketer_name = $row[1];
        $status = $row[2];
        $mar = $row[3];
        $hin = $row[4];
        $eng = $row[5];
        $hist = $row[6];
        $geo = $row[7];
        $marks = $row[8];

        $sql_result1 = mysql_query("SELECT `cricketer_name` FROM `bat_score_board` WHERE `cricketer_name` =  '".$_POST['studentId1']."' ") or die(mysql_error());
        $sql_row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_result1);
        if(!empty($sql_row1['cricketer_name'])) {
            //echo "Id exists - " .  $sql_row1['cricketer_name'] . "\n";
            $sqlup1 = " update bat_score_board set 
                        cricketer_name= '".$_POST['studentId1']."', 
                        status='".$_POST['Status1']."', 
                        mar='".$_POST['mar1']."', 
                        hin= '".$_POST['hin1']."', 
                        eng='".$_POST['eng1']."', 
                        hist='".$_POST['hist1']."', 
                        geo='".$_POST['geo1']."', 
                        marks='".$_POST['marks1']."'            
                        where cricketer_name='".$_POST['studentId1']."' ";
            $resultup1 = mysql_query($sqlup1);
            //print_r($resultup1); exit();
        } else {
            //echo "Id no longer exists - " . $sql_row1['cricketer_name'] . "\n";
            $sqlBat1 = "INSERT INTO bat_score_board(cricketer_name, status, mar, hin, eng, hist, geo, marks)VALUES
            '(".$_POST['studentId1']."', 
            '".$_POST['Status1']."', 
            '".$_POST['mar1']."', 
            '".$_POST['hin1']."', 
            '".$_POST['eng1']."', 
            '".$_POST['hist1']."',
            '".$_POST['geo1']."', 
            '".$_POST['marks1']."')";

            $resultBat1 = mysql_query($sqlBat1);
            //print_r($resultBat1); exit();
        }   

        }



        ?>
```

Comment: i am just passing the value of label in database.

Comment: @Shri what's the condition for selecting $student1 on your studentId1 (hidden field).
Provide more code..

Comment: @Shri how did you fetch the value?

Comment: require("/includes/commonClass.php");
 
 $classObj = new commonclass;
 
 $postedData = $classObj->getRequestedData();
 
 $setsession = $classObj->validsessionmanager();



$classObj->getTempteam();
              
$resultum = $classObj->selectSql($condum);
$rowum = $classObj->fetchData($resultum);
   
foreach($rowum as $rowsum)
    {
 $student1 = $rowsum['student_name1'];
 $student2 = $rowsum['student_name2'];
 $student3 = $rowsum['student_name3'];
 $student4 = $rowsum['student_name4'];
 
 
}

Comment: i am using it by creating classObj from commonClass.php file

Comment: @Shri in 
$resultum = $classObj->selectSql($condum); 
$condum? write down the actual query, not variable.

Comment: i think problem is not in fetching data may be it is in saving data. and my all query regarding my project is in commonClass.php file.